# How to get card number and cvv details in react native expo(stripe)

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

How to get cvv and card number from given card details in expo project for stripe payment method.

```
<CardField
          
          postalCodeEnabled={false}
          
          placeholder={{
            number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
          }}
          cardStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            textColor: '#000000',
          }}
          style={{ height: 50, }}
          onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
            setCardDetails(cardDetails)
          }}
        
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the card details when `onCardChange` call every time the value change like

```
onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
  // here "cardDetails" is the object and you can get the value like

  const validNumber = cardDetails.validNumber;
  const validCVC = cardDetails.validCVC;
}}
```